# Limit to zero of two variables

Tags: calculus, limits

Given functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, suppose that the values $$A=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(f(h)\lim_{i\rightarrow 0}g(h,i)\right)$$ and $$B=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(h)g(h,h)$$ exist. Do they have to be equal?

It looks like they really should be, since the limit is just when the variables $h,i$ go to zero (i.e. every variable goes to zero), but it seems hard to prove using the delta-epsilon definition.

Comment: Did you mean to type $g(i)$ instead of $g(h,i)$ so that the domain of $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @Adriano Oh, thanks for pointing out. I meant $g$ takes value both $h$ and $i$, so its domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to at least put some kind of regularity conditions on your functions: Let $f(x) = 1$ be the constant function, and let
$$g(h,i) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}i/h, & h \not= 0, \\0, & h = 0. \end{array} \right.$$
Then assuming that the limits are set up so that $i \not= 0$, $h \not= 0$,
$$A = \lim_{h\to 0} 1 \cdot 0 = 0, \quad B = \lim_{h\to 0} 1\cdot 1 = 1.$$