# Value of $f''(c)$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Suppose $f$ is defined in $[a,b]$ and $c\in(a,b)$ and suppose $f'$ exists in an open interval containing $c$ and that $f''(c)$ exists. Show that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(c+2h)-2f(c+h)+f(c)}{h^2}=f''(c)$$ Give an example to show that the limit above may exist even though $f'(c)$ does not exist.

So following the definitions, we have $$f''(c)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\dfrac{\lim_{i\rightarrow0}\dfrac{f(c+h+i)-f(c+h)-f(c+i)+f(c)}{i}}{h}$$

I don't know how to show that this quantity is equal to the quantity in question. Also, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426727/limit-to-zero-of-two-variables) shows that it's not possible to pull out the limit for any function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Using Taylor's Theorem one can write

$$f(c+2h)=f(c)+f'(c)2h+f''(c)2h^2+o(h^2)$$

$$2f(c+h)=2f(c)+f'(c)2h+f''(c)h^2+o(h^2)$$

Thus

$$f(c+2h)-2f(c+h)+f(c)=f''(c)h^2+o(h^2)$$

Which is what we wanted.

Answer (score 3):

For an example of where this limit exists while the first derivative doesn't exist, take $f(x)=|x|$ in $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left[\frac{f(c+2h)-f(c+h)}{h}-\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}\right]=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}[f'(c+h+\epsilon_h)-f'(c+\delta_h)]=f''(c)$$

where $\epsilon_h$ and $\delta_h$ are chosen according to mean value theorem:
$$ f(c+2h)-f(c+h)=h f'(c+h+\epsilon_h)$$
and
$$ f(c+h)-f(c)= h f'(c+\delta_h)$$
and $\epsilon_h\to 0$ and $\delta_h\to 0$ as $h\to 0$.

Comment: Err... did you "use up" $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}$ twice? Why not use the mean value theorem instead?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Oooppss.. totally overlooked that. Does this look good now?

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, you will see that if $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \lim_{i \rightarrow 0} g(h,i)$ exists for a function $g$, then $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} g(h,h)$ must also exist, and be equal to the first limit. (Of course the converse is not true.) This gives you your target expression immediately.